# Explain How to restrict user login via web app and allow login via mobile app only in Java and spring framework?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I m New to stackoverflow

How to detect user is login from webapp and retrict user login
(different techniques )
and allow login via mobile app only

Comment: You can make use of the User-Agent being sent in the header

Comment: @Gautam easy to fake UA

Comment: I know, any better ideas :) ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Though your question is a valid one, I think it is [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO. This kind of question can attract very opinionated answers, which may not be so beneficial. Personally, I think such open ended questions are more suited for Quora.